# How do I sum all columns in a table with the same classname in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to sum a price in a table, all the prices in the `<td>` have the same class name and I'd like to sum them up on a button click. I would eventually like to calculate the quantity into the total as well. This is what I have so far:

```js
function sumAmounts() {
  var sum = 0;
  var listPriceTotal = $('.txtListPrice').each(function() {
    sum += parseFloat($(this).html); // Or this.innerHTML, this.innerText
  });
  document.getElementById("txtTotal").value = listPriceTotal;
}

document.getElementById("addTotals").addEventListener("click", () => {
  sumAmounts();


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <th><label>SKU</label></th>
    <th><label>Retail Price</label></th>
    <th><label>List Price</label></th>
    <th><label>Product Name</label></th>
    <th><label>Quantity</label></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="txtSKU">1234</td>
    <td class="txtRetailPrice">12.50</td>
    <td class="txtListPrice">11.75</td>
    <td class="txtProductName">product 1</td>
    <td class="txtQuantity"><input type="text"> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="txtSKU">12222</td>
    <td class="txtRetailPrice">14.50</td>
    <td class="txtListPrice">9.75</td>
    <td class="txtProductName">product 2</td>
    <td class="txtQuantity"><input type="text"> </td>
  </tr>
  <tfoot>
    <th><label id="lblTotal">Total:</label><input type="text" name="txtTotal" id="txtTotal">
      <input type="button" value="Add" id="addTotals">
    </th>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: `.html` should be `.html()` as it is a function. But the other options in the comment would also work. So... What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two issues in your code. Firstly you're trying to set a jQuery object as the value of the `input`, which is why you see `[Object object]` in the field. You need to set the value to `sum`.

The second issue is that you're supplying the `html` method *reference* to `parseFloat()`, not the actual `html()` value. With both of those addressed, the code works:

```js
function sumAmounts() {
  var sum = 0;
  $('.txtListPrice').each(function() {
    sum += parseFloat($(this).html());
  });
  document.getElementById("txtTotal").value = sum;
}

document.getElementById("addTotals").addEventListener("click", () => {
  sumAmounts();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <th><label>SKU</label></th>
    <th><label>Retail Price</label></th>
    <th><label>List Price</label></th>
    <th><label>Product Name</label></th>
    <th><label>Quantity</label></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="txtSKU">1234</td>
    <td class="txtRetailPrice">12.50</td>
    <td class="txtListPrice">11.75</td>
    <td class="txtProductName">product 1</td>
    <td class="txtQuantity"><input type="text"> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="txtSKU">12222</td>
    <td class="txtRetailPrice">14.50</td>
    <td class="txtListPrice">9.75</td>
    <td class="txtProductName">product 2</td>
    <td class="txtQuantity"><input type="text"> </td>
  </tr>
  <tfoot>
    <th>
      <label id="lblTotal">Total:</label>
      <input type="text" name="txtTotal" id="txtTotal">
      <input type="button" value="Add" id="addTotals">
    </th>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```